# It is possible to position a slider on a discrete seekBar on continious values in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

I have the following seekBar in Android with 5 discrete values:

```xml
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar_Sweetness"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_14sdp"
    android:max="4"
    android:maxHeight="4dip"
    android:minHeight="4dip"
    android:progress="2"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_ruler_rate"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_bar_slider_beer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView_numberOfRatings"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_ratingLabel"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_ratingLabel"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barChartRatings"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />
```

which looks like this

[image]

Now My question is if it is possible to position the slider (programmatically) on any continious value between the discrete ones? I want to set the slider from my Java code and fix it at that place, so it should not something the user should interact with, it is rather a source for informationen (based on the percentages of the discrete values).

**Reminder**: Any ideas or advice regarding this issue?

Comment: SInce you have set the max value at 4, i guess you cant set on any continuous value here. since the progress wont accept fractional value!

Comment: You can try setting max to 100 and set the your discrete values at intervals of 25 so in this way you can slider on any continous value too!

Comment: @MohammedJunaid: Thanks Mohammed for your comments. "You can try setting max to 100 and set the your discrete values at intervals of 25 so in this way you can slider on any continous value too!" --> how can I do that?

Comment: @MohammedJunaid: Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you as I still have not solved this problem.

Comment: @MohammedJunaid: any further advice?